# how to fetch value from input field in ionic framework?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

below are two ionic tags for email and password:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label color="primary" floating>Email id</ion-label>
    <ion-input id = "email" type="email" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
    <ion-label color="primary" floating>Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input id = "pass" type="password" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

how can i fetch the text data from the field and assign it to a variable in angularjs 2 using typeScript?

Answer (score 0):

Use two way binding: `<ion-input id = "pass" type="password" ng-model="pass"></ion-input>`

In angular:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
.controller('nameofcontroller',function($scope){
 var formPost = {
      "Pass":pass
    };
console.log(formpost);

    $scope.pass=formPost;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label color="primary" floating>Email id</ion-label>
    <ion-input id = "email" ng-model="user.email" type="email" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
    <ion-label color="primary" floating>Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input id = "pass" ng-model="user.password" type="password" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

add `ng-model`

Now in controller

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
.controller('nameofcontroller',function($scope){
```

use ..

`$scope.user.email;`
`$scope.user.password;`

like .. `console.log('User is :',$scope.user.email);`

Comment: console.log('User is :',$scope.user.email); doesn't show anything in console